# Прием оплат на Android

Tags: android

Здравствуйте

Существует ли возможность приёма оплат в Android приложениях? 
Интересуют WebMoney, ЯндексДеньги, РобоКасса, LiqPay, payPal, Qiwi, RBKMoney

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот к примеру у палки [есть sdk для для андроида](http://mobile-developer.ru/google-android/integriruem-oplatu-cherez-paypal-v-android-prilozhenie/), так что можно прикрутить

Думаю, что если погуглить, то и что нибудь из списка еще найдется.

**UPD**

[Yandex Money](https://github.com/melnikovdv/Java-Yandex.Money-API-SDK)